# Navigator Vs ViewPagerAndroid

Tags: react-native

What is the difference between Navigator & ViewPagerAndroid components in React-Native? And when to use them? 
Seems like both can be used to navigate between different screens of the app.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that React Native is not a "write once, run anywhere" solution. Thus, it includes modules that are platform-specific and merely wrap a component natively available on iOS/Android.

One such component is **ViewPagerAndroid**. This just wraps Android's "ViewPager" component and provides similar functionality to natively using the ViewPager. This component should be used when you have a carousel-like layout in which multiple Views are laid out horizontally, and you wish to animate between them:

[image]

**Navigator** is a cross-platform component that allows you to switch what is currently shown on the screen easily. The Navigator has no concept of hierarchy or order (unlike ViewPagerAndroid), and you can switch to any other View at any time.

Comment: and Navigator is more customizable through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**ViewPagerAndroid** is more of a swipe component for tabbing. If you use it more, you will find that in some cases it might be limiting.

**Navigator** lets you push/navigate to and from screen/pages and keeps track of it in a stack. Navigator here is more versatile in terms of [transitions between scenes](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/navigator.html#configurescene). It also plays nice with hardware back button on androids.

For example, lets say you have bottom navigation of Discover, Search and Profile, but in Profile screen you would also have tabs of Feed, Following and Followers. In this setup you would need two ViewPagerAndroid components witch is impossible.

It would also be a bad UX practice because a user might want to swipe between Followers and Following, but would suddenly swipe away from Profile to Search.

**Pro tip:**
On the other hand Navigator components can be combined one within another. This is something I did't know initially and was struggling with. What I have in my apps usually is two Navigator components. One to handle tabs between my main scenes (e.g. Discover, Search and Profile) that are loaded in TabNavigator on start. I navigate between them with a [jumpTo](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/navigator.html#jumpto) and custom transition less [configureScene](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/navigator.html#configurescene).

```
configureScene(route, routeStack) { //- this all is a hacky way to make no transitions
    var NoTransition = {
        opacity: {
            value: 1.0,
            type: "constant",
        },
    };

    return  {
        ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid,
        gestures: null,
        defaultTransitionVelocity: 1000,
        animationInterpolators: {
            into: buildStyleInterpolator(NoTransition),
            out: buildStyleInterpolator(NoTransition),
        },
    };
}
```

This way user can jump between main scenes and progress/changes in each scene are not lost (like scrolling down a list) just like ViewPagerAndroid. Then I have other MainNavigator which I use to navigate to push and pop individual scenes like Single (display some sort of content from a list). First or initial scene of MainNavigator is TabNavigator.